# Signalr in a separate library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, with a library for my business logic. I want to use Signalr for chatting, however the messages should be validated, recorded to database, and maybe emailed to recipient if he is not online.

My question is: Is it better to install Signalr in my business logic library, or put it in a separate library, or keep it in the ASP.NET application because of the hubs?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is already a separate library. You just need to add a reference or install it via PM:

```
PM> install-package SignalR
```

If you are talking about another abstract layer, here is my opinion:

- You don't need any abstract layers till the moment you're really need them
- Multiple abstract layers can significantly over complicate your overall project structure
- Add abstract layers as soon as you need them

Read this article: [Evolutionary Project Structure](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/30/evolutionary-project-structure/) ([cached in google](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aLB0piShLlrYJ%3alostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/30/evolutionary-project-structure/%20&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)).

Practices that may help:

- [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)
- [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You are saying not to create any layer except my ASP.NET MVC project, put all my logic there, and reference the projects which I need.
Currently I have 3 layers, MVC, BLL, & DAL. There are some libraries which are referenced by MVC (like Elmah, DotNetOpenAuth,...) and others which are referenced by BLL (like clamson, dal, etc...)
It makes sense for me to create the BLL for future modifications/debugging/testing. I might also reuse the library for windows service purpose.

Comment: I mean don't create any layers until you really need them. It looks like in your case you are really need them. So it's okay if you have a separate library.As for SignalR, I think it's a good idea to use this library only in ASP.NET MVC project until the moment you will need to use it somewhere else.If you will use it somewhere else, it means you may need abstraction layer to wrap it around. Or you even can use the library itself even in lots of your projects inside of solution (just adding a reference).It's like you add a reference to System.Configuration in order to use ConfigurationManager.